# Can i create object of my class containing array?

Tags: java

I have small problem with my code. Can I put a table (array) in the class constructor? When I put types like int/string my class works perfectly but when I try put an array `int[][]`into the constructor of  every object of my class, it always returns the last value of the array. Is there a way to put a table (array) inside the constructor?

Example code:

```
public class Population {
 int[][] population_object;
 int test;  

public Population(int[][] population_object){
    this.population_object = population_object;
}


public int[][] population_print(){
    return this.population_object;
    }

}
```

And using it:

```
static ArrayList<Population> population_list;
population_list = new ArrayList<Population>();
Population buff = new Population(pupulation_object_buffor);
population_list.add(buff);
```

This returns only the last added table (array)... Objects of course do not contain the same table `(population_object_buffor)`.

```
int[][] test = population_list.get(s).population_print();

for(int k=0; k<test.length; k++){
                for(int kk=0; kk<test[k].length; kk++){
                    System.out.print(" "+test[k][kk]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I fixed it... Sorry.

Comment: If `pupulation_object_buffor` is your `int[][]`, then all your `Population` instances will share the same population object.

Comment: Yes pupulation_object_buffor is int[][].
It's some way to have different population object for instances? I would like to have arraylist of objects and every objects should have unique table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you initialise your `Population` object:

```
public class Population
{
    private int[][] object;

    public Population(int[][] object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < object[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(object[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Population> population = new ArrayList<>();

    // 5 Population
    for (int nr = 1; nr <= 5; nr++) {
        // each Population has an int[5][5]
        int[][] object = new int[5][5];
        // int the object
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            object[i][j] = nr;
        // add the Population with the object just created
        population.add(new Population(object));
    }

    // print out each Population object
    for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Population " + (i + 1) + ":");
        population.get(i).print();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Population 1:
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111

Population 2:
22222
22222
22222
22222
22222

Population 3:
33333
33333
33333
33333
33333

Population 4:
44444
44444
44444
44444
44444

Population 5:
55555
55555
55555
55555
55555
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is very good! But.. The problem is that my whole code looks like yours.. but it doesn't work.... I know that yours work.. could you help me why it doesnt work? Here is link to pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/MiSLzQpV

Comment: That's because in your code you have *only one instance* of `int[][] pupulation_object_buffor`. That instance is used in the `main()`, where you change its value, and is passed through all your `Population` objects. So, your `Population` objects all refer to the same instance of `int[][]` object. As you can see,  in my code, I declare an `int[][] object` for each `Population` (`new int[5][5];`).

Comment: Yes! It's true.. You made my day! You really help me a lot! Thank you very mutch! :)

Comment: Not at all! However, simply create a `new int[][]` in your `inicjalizacja_populacji()` method instead of call `clean_buffor()`: `pupulation_object_buffor = new int[...][...]`. It should work.

Comment: I fix it as you sad. I'm very grateful for your help. Thank you :)